# undeclared indentifier on the same scope C++

Tags: c++, module, c++20

Playing with `C++ 20` modules, I have the following snippet:

```
export {

    template<class T>
    class Suite {
        private:
            std::vector<ConcreteBuilder<T>> things {};
    };

    template <class T>
    class ConcreteBuilder : Builder<T> {
        private:
            // A collection of things of function pointers or functors
            std::vector<std::function<void()>> things;

        public:
            // Virtual destructor
            virtual ~TestBuilder() override {};
            // Add a new thing to the collection of things
            template<typename Function>
            void add(Function&& fn) {  
                tests.push_back(std::forward<Function>(fn)); 
            }
            // override the build() base method from Builder<T>
            virtual T build() const override {
                return this->things;
            }
    };
}
```

And I am getting this `Clang` error:

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'ConcreteBuilder'
std::vector<ConcreteBuilder> things {};
```

Why I can't access to a type that are in the same module at the same level?

Comment: Because you are referencing it before you define it.

Comment: Essentially C++ uses a single pass compilation process.  If it see's something being used that it hasn't yet seen, that is generally going to result in an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler compiles the file from the top down, not all at once. It is hitting the definition of `std::vector<ConcreteBuilder<T>>` before it gets to the definition of `class ConcreteBuilder`.

So, you need to move your definition of `Suite` after the definition of `ConcreteBuilder`, so the compiler knows what it is when you use it in the vector definition.